# How to connect SQlite database to devcpp?

Tags: c++, sqlite, dev-c++

Can anyone help me to connect Devcpp to SQLite? I want to create a departmental store database management system project in C++, I am using devcpp and wanted to connect my SQLite database which I created in DB Browser(SQLite) with Devcpp.

Comment: The simplest way is here: [https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite can not connect to devcpp but if you want to connect  sqlite to cpp. you can find answer on google.